# How do I use symlink in place of NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, symlink

I have an app that has been using `NODE_PATH` for a few years. If I move to ES6 natively, rather than using the `esm` package, that no longer works. The docs at https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_node_path simply say:

```
NODE_PATH is not part of resolving import specifiers. Please use symlinks if this behavior is desired.
```

There is no reference on how to do this. I basically just had the line `NODE_PATH=./src/` this entire time and want to replicate it so when I do `import middleware/file.js` it maps to `middleware` being in the `src` folder.

I've done `symlink` for folders on my machine, but not sure how `nodejs` would register such things for when I deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a unix-based system you could solve your particular issue with:

```
ln -s ./src/* node_modules/
```

For more universal approach to shimming `NODE_PATH` with symlinks:

```
mkdir -p node_modules
IFS=:
for path in $NODE_PATH; do
  ln -s $path/* node_modules/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

NODE_PATH support was deprecated in v4 i believe, now it should be set in jsconfig or tsconfig instead,

If you are using javascript with your project, add jsconfig.json file to your project root, and add the following code to that file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```